# Inflate a polyline so that the 2D band can be triangulated without self-intersections

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons, triangulation

**Introduction**

I have simple polylines as sequences of points. I need a triangulation with a configurable width. The goal is to get a 2D 'band' from the input polyline without self-intersections.

**Description:**

Input is a 2D point sequence {P1, ..., Pn} (Polyline) and a target width of the triangulated band. Output is the triangulation without self intersection:
[image]

In the current implementation I move the segments formed by {P1, .., Pn} in both perpendicular directions. The outline points to be triangulated are calculated by intersection of the translated segments (red dots in the image above).

The problem with this approach is that in sharp angles the resulting intersection points generate self-intersecting triangles:

[image]

**Question**

Is there a robust algorithm to triangulate a band from a polyline without generating self-intersections?

**References:**

- [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation) approach seems to be similar but also does not solve the self intersection problem
- [Clipper2](https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Clipper2) has an InflatePath method that does the offset but I don't know how to triangulate the resulting path
- An approach would be to just triangulate the outline points with [Delaunay](https://cartography-playground.gitlab.io/playgrounds/triangulation-delaunay-voronoi-diagram/) but I don't know how to restrict the result to triangles inside the 'Band'
- A very nice explanation of [Constrained Delaunay Triangulation](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/TinfourDocs/DelaunayIntroCDT/index.html)

Comment: It is not clear how the outline should look like. Please be specific. (One method is to build the outline, then triangulate it.)

Comment: Thank for the comment. I added an image with input and output, I hope that helps to clarify the issue. I'm currently looking at constrained Delaunay triangulation

Comment: That does not address my question. I said outline.

Comment: Also, why have you rejected the approach Yves Daoust suggests of building the outline, then triangulating it?  What does "suffer from self-intersections" mean and why is that a problem?  What does "robust" mean in this context?  What approaches have you already considered and why have you rejected them?  Are you asking how to build the outline?

Comment: The outline the result of translating the points of the inner polygon {P1, ... Pn} to the outside. This is where the self-intersection is coming in, since it is has the same problem as a polygon offset. So the outline points are not really reliable. Using these outline points leads to a triangulation with self-intersections

Comment: And you still don't tell us how the outline should look like. By the way, if your desired shape is *not* an offset, I even less understand what you are after.

Comment: Ok, I see this is harder to explain than I thought. I'll add a more detailed drawing when I have some time. Thanks for hanging in here

Comment: We know very well what an offset is. But we can't guess how you want to handle the last figure.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "inflated polyline" can be correctly defined as a *union* of "inflated line segments". Each such "inflated line segment" will be a rectangle with half-disks on its two opposite ends, describing all points $p \in \Bbb R^2$, such that their distance from the segment is not more than a (configurable) constant $W$:

[image: Inflated-polyline]

However you'll get an area with *circular arcs* on its boundary, so it'll be not easy to triangulate it. Probably you don't need all this heavy artillery, like the Delaunay triangulation - a couple of simple heuristics will do the job for you.

For example, to solve the problem with intersecting triangles in case of sharp turns you need to consider not only pairs of adjacent segments - you need to **analyze longer chains of segments** and skip segments, which don't contribute to the boundary. Please see below - the segment $s2$ doesn't contribute to the boundary, because it's located too deep inside the "inflated polyline". The point, marked by red color, belongs to the boundary of the union of two "inflated line segments" $s1$ and $s3$, so this point should be the triangulation vertex:

[image: Skipped-segment]

Please note, that this segment $s2$ can't be ignored on the other side of the polyline. These ignored segments can appear in groups, and be on both sides of the polyline. As a result, this triangulation won't be so simple and regular compared to your one.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is indeed helpful. I will consider such an 'heuristic' approach and drop the idea of using CDT. As far as I understand it it is not the right use case for CDT anyways.